# Build an Input value based on other multiple input values

Tags: javascript

I have a set of form fields that exist like

```
<input type="text" name="item" id="item" value="">
<input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" value="">
<input type="text" name="place" id="place" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="somecode" name="somecode" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="op" id="op" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="result" id="result" value="">
```

What I need is for the `result` field to be auto updated as data is entered in the other fields with a double `-` added between them, so the result would look like

```
Item--desc--place--somecode--op
```

The site I have uses jquery for other javascript on the site so if that is useful to get the desired result then great (but not essential)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work assuming you can add a class to each item. Although I'm not sure it will trigger when the hidden value changes, do you need it to?

```
$('input.test').change(function() {
    $('#result').val($('#item').val() + "--" + $('#desc').val() + "--" + $('#place').val() + "--" + $('#somecode').val() + "--" + $('#op').val());
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/k6wA4/)

Comment: Thanks I will try this shortly, and no the hidden value is static so that is fine.  Thanks again.